# Transform an entity from a type to another

Tags: c#

I need to transform an entity from an external DLL to another entity which is from a different external DLL.

My question is: Is this the best solution or is there a better solution (type-save)? I hope there is a better idee because I don't really like to use the dynamic type.

```
using ExternalDllOne.Fruit; //contains(Apple, Banana, Melon, Peach)
using ExternalDllTwo.Fruit; //contains(ReturnApple, ReturnBanana, ReturnMelon, ReturnPeach)

public static dynamic Transform(Type type, string path)
{
    switch (type.Name)
    {
        case nameof(Banana):
            {
                Banana serializedFruit = SerializerFactory<Banana>.Create(SerializerType.Xml).Deserialize(path);
                ReturnBanana fruit = TransformBanana(serializedFruit);
                return fruit;
            }
        case nameof(Apple):
            {
                Apple serializedFruit = SerializerFactory<Apple>.Create(SerializerType.Xml).Deserialize(path);
                ReturnApple fruit =  TransformApple(serializedFruit);
                return fruit;
            }
        case nameof(Peach):
            {
                Peach serializedFruit = SerializerFactory<Peach>.Create(SerializerType.Xml).Deserialize(path);
                ReturnPeach fruit =  TransformPeach(serializedFruit);
                return fruit;
            }
        case nameof(Melon):
            {
                Melon serializedFruit = SerializerFactory<Melon>.Create(SerializerType.Xml).Deserialize(path);
                ReturnMelon fruit =  TransformMelon(serializedFruit);
                return fruit;
            }
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException($@"Type: [{type.Name}] is not a valid type for this application");
    }
}
```

The conversion is done thru a facade which is located in an external DLL. They way the `Transform<fruit>()` works is for every fruit type the same:

```
private static ReturnBanana TransformBanana(Banana fruit)
{
    var extraSettings = GetBananaSettings();

    var transformedFruit = FruitTransformationFacade.Transform(fruit, extraSettings);

    return transformedFruit;
}
```

Using the transformer method I have this code:

```
private static dynamic Load(string path)
{
    XDocument document = FileHelper.ParseFile(path);

    Type fileType = TypeHelper.DetermineFileType(document);

    dynamic component = Transformer.Transform(fileType, path);

    return component;
}
```

Do I need a wrapper object for each `Return<fruit>` entity with a coherent Interface, and return the interface?

Comment: Could add more information about the entities and the conversion process?

Comment: The entities are all different and have nothing in common with eachother except that they are serializable.

Comment: Do you have only SerializerFactory<T> or also a non-generic version where T is a Type parameter?

Comment: I only have the generic version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't really like the other answer, basically it says you must return object instead, and wants more POCO's (one for each object) that handles everything. There's a more *dynamic* (pun-intended) way to avoid `dynamic`.

Let's think about this from a more abstract standpoint: we want to take *any* object and transform it to any *other* object assuming we have a transform method for it.

I made an assembly, Console application, and started playing with it and created a namespace `First` and a `Second`, threw some `Fruit` types together, and it looks like so:

```
namespace CSharp_Test1.First
{
    public class Apple
    {
        public string Color { get; } = "Red";
    }
}

namespace CSharp_Test1.First
{
    public class Banana
    {
        public string Color { get; } = "Yellowish";

        public int Count { get; set; } = -5;
    }
}

namespace CSharp_Test1.Second
{
    public class OtherApple
    {
        public string Color { get; } = "Other Red";
    }
}

namespace CSharp_Test1.Second
{
    public class OtherBanana
    {
        public string Color { get; } = "Other Yellowish";

        public int Count { get; set; } = 5;
    }
}
```

I gave `Banana` and `OtherBanana` a `Count` *only* to prove a point, because my serialization mock is pretty lame and I didn't want to build actual serialization as it doesn't matter:

```
public class Serializer<T>
    where T : new()
{
    public T Deserialize(string path) =>
        new T();
}

public static class SerializerFactory<T>
    where T : new()
{
    public static Serializer<T> Create(SerializerType type) =>
        new Serializer<T>();
}

public enum SerializerType
{
    Xml
}
```

Now you can call `SerializerFactory<T>.Create(SerializerType).Deserialize(string)` and get a `T` from it, but we're not going to do that.

Now how do we wrap a generic `SerializerFactory<T>.Create(SerializerType).Deserialize(string)` construct? With a `NonGenericSerializer`:

```
public class NonGenericSerializer
{
    private object _rootSerializer;

    public object Deserialize(string path) =>
        _rootSerializer
            .GetType()
            .GetMethod("Deserialize")
            .Invoke(_rootSerializer, new object[] { path });

    public static NonGenericSerializer Create(Type type, SerializerType serializerType)
    {
        var ngs = new NonGenericSerializer();
        var factory = typeof(SerializerFactory<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { type });
        ngs._rootSerializer = factory.GetMethod("Create").Invoke(factory, new object[] { serializerType });
        return ngs;
    }
}
```

We use a boatload of reflection, but it's pretty simple. We use `object` instead of `dynamic`, and we have to call `NonGenericSerializer.Create(Type, SerializerType).Deserialize(string)`, but it works.

At this point I want to talk about the transformations: we have a method for each object type as you mentioned:

```
private static OtherApple Transform(Apple apple) =>
    new OtherApple();

private static OtherBanana Transform(Banana banana) =>
    new OtherBanana() { Count = banana.Count };
```

Pretty simple, I didn't pull all your code as I didn't need it, I just needed a mock.

Within our transformation system we need to find a method dynamically, sorta. We want to find the method that has the **return type** of our input parameter. Of course I should mention that the final API call will look like this:

```
OtherApple otherApple = TransformUtilities.Transform<OtherApple>("some path");
```

Right, back to `TransformUtilities`, we need a `Transform<T>(string path)` method:

```
public static T Transform<T>(string path)
{
    var transformMethod = GetTransformMethod<T>();
    return Transform<T>(NonGenericSerializer.Create(
        transformMethod.GetParameters().First().ParameterType,
        SerializerType.Xml
    ).Deserialize(path));
}
```

That makes sense, we want to find the method we're transforming with, then deserialize it (**non**-generically), then provide that value to the transform method.

```
private static T Transform<T>(object item) =>
    (T)typeof(TransformUtilities)
        .GetMethod("Transform",
                   BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static,
                   null,
                   new Type[] { item.GetType() },
                   null)
        .Invoke(null, new object[] { item });
```

So we invoke the method in the `Transform<T>(object)` method.

```
private static MethodInfo GetTransformMethod<T>()
{
    var typeFullName = typeof(T).FullName;
    var candidateMethods =
        typeof(TransformUtilities)
            .GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.ExactBinding)
            .Where(x => x.Name == "Transform");

    if (!candidateMethods.Any(x => x.ReturnType.FullName == typeFullName))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($@"Type: [{typeFullName}] is not a valid type for this application");
    }

    return candidateMethods
        .First(x => x.ReturnType.FullName == typeFullName);
}
```

And finally we find the appropriate method.

All this boils down to the following: now when you want to transform a `Peach` to an `OtherPeach`, you simple create a `public static OtherPeach Transform(Peach obj)` method.

My main looks like the following:

```
Console.WriteLine(TransformUtilities.Transform<OtherApple>("some path").Color);
Console.WriteLine(TransformUtilities.Transform<OtherBanana>("some path").Color);
Console.WriteLine(TransformUtilities.Transform<OtherBanana>("some path").Count);
```

Pretty freaking simple. If we have a `Transform` method, then we can do the transformation, if not then we have that exception.

As a test, consider the following method in `Transform`:

```
private static string Transform(int value) => (value + 150).ToString();
```

And call it:

```
Console.WriteLine(TransformUtilities.Transform<string>("some path"));
```

Output is `150`. Remove the `Transform` method and the exception is thrown:

> **System.ArgumentException**: 'Type: [System.String] is not a valid type for this application'

Is this a lot of boilerplate? Not really but we could go with 'Sure' I guess. Does it make adding/removing transformations *stupid* simple? Damn right. You could also create a `Transformations` class which has the `private static Other____ Transform(____ obj)` methods, and modify the `GetTransformMethod<T>()` and `T Transform<T>(object)` method as follows:

```
private static MethodInfo GetTransformMethod<T>()
{
    var typeFullName = typeof(T).FullName;
    var candidateMethods =
        typeof(Transformations)
            .GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.ExactBinding)
            .Where(x => x.Name == "Transform");

    if (!candidateMethods.Any(x => x.ReturnType.FullName == typeFullName))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($@"Type: [{typeFullName}] is not a valid type for this application");
    }

    return candidateMethods
        .First(x => x.ReturnType.FullName == typeFullName);
}

private static T Transform<T>(object item) =>
    (T)typeof(Transformations)
        .GetMethod("Transform",
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static,
                    null,
                    new Type[] { item.GetType() },
                    null)
        .Invoke(null, new object[] { item });
```

(Basically, the `typeof(Transformations)` should be the class name where the `Transform` methods are.)

This changes your `Load` to:

```
private static T Load<T>(string path)
{
    XDocument document = FileHelper.ParseFile(path);

    T component = Transformer.Transform(path);

    return component;
}
```

Of course you could also remove the type-safety from `Load` and eliminate `dynamic` by returning an `object`, but then you have to type-case and such.

Since you mention (in comments) that you have **no** idea about the return type *at all*, I've come up with a modification that works for *both* scenarios.

We *had* the `GetTransformMethod<T>()` which would take type `T` and find the method that had the best return, well now we have a `GetTransformedMethod<T>()` which does the opposite: given type `T` find the best method to transform it.

```
private static MethodInfo GetTransformedMethod<T>()
{
    var typeFullName = typeof(T).FullName;
    var candidateMethods =
        typeof(TransformUtilities)
            .GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.ExactBinding)
            .Where(x => x.Name == "Transform");

    if (!candidateMethods.Any(x => x.GetParameters().First().ParameterType.FullName == typeFullName))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($@"Type: [{typeFullName}] is not a valid type for this application");
    }

    return candidateMethods
        .First(x => x.GetParameters().First().ParameterType.FullName == typeFullName);
}
```

Then we create a simple `Transform(Type, object)` method that will find the `Transform` method that fits and call it, then return the result as an `object`. You can then pass that *directly* to a serializer which should be able to serialize it appropriate.

```
public static object Transform(Type type, string path)
{
    var result = NonGenericSerializer.Create(
        type,
        SerializerType.Xml
    ).Deserialize(path);

    var transformLocateMethod =
        typeof(TransformUtilities)
            .GetMethod("GetTransformedMethod", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

    var transformMethod = (MethodInfo)transformLocateMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { result.GetType() }).Invoke(null, null);

    return transformMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { result });
}
```

And our new test calls:

```
Console.WriteLine(((OtherApple)TransformUtilities.Transform(typeof(Apple), "some path")).Color);
Console.WriteLine(((OtherBanana)TransformUtilities.Transform(typeof(Banana), "some path")).Color);
Console.WriteLine(((OtherBanana)TransformUtilities.Transform(typeof(Banana), "some path")).Count);
```

---

I suggest you evaluate your code, and determine why such a *seemingly* simple task has been blown out of proportion. *Usually* you need to know a type for loading/saving behavior to work properly, so I'm curious where you call `Load` that doesn't care about what *actual* type it is.

Comment: Well, if all you have is a `Type` object then generics won't help you and since OP is using this as a parameter one can assume that he does not have the `T`, otherwise I guess he would already have made it generic because apparently he knows how it works. So yes, you are right, my solution is an _ugly_ workaround for `dynamic`.

Comment: @t3chb0t I did go under the assumption that the OP knows the *return* type, if not then a lot of the type coercion from this could be removed, and simply return `object` from the `public static T Transform<T>(string path)`, remove the `<T>` constraint, and you're good to go.

Comment: @t3chb0t is right. I only know the input type, Not the return type. This application should read a xml file. Determine the xml type and transform this type to another type and deserialize again. So i cant use generics on Load().

Comment: @PolkaHard Added more to the answer that *should* do what you want.

Comment: @EBrown I will give it a go, I will let you know the result. Thanks to both of your help so far!

Comment: This works for replacing the dynamic. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> public static dynamic Transform(Type type, string path)
> ```

If I should return an object of any type I'd rather use the `object` type for it then `dynamic`. I don't know how you actually use it so I assume that all objects have some set of common properties but don't share a any common interface.

In that case I think it would make more sense to create an artifical wrapper for those objects so that you can read those properties (or methods) without having to use `dynamic` everywhere.

```
public class Fruit // = ExternalDllTwoEntityWrapper
{ 
    private readonly dynamic _value;
    Fruit(object obj) => _value = obj;
    public string Name => (string)_value.Name;
}
```

Whether you use `dynamic` or reflection internally to access those properties is another question.

If you however can change one of those external dlls then an abstraction would be the obvious way to solve this:

```
public interface IFruit
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```